# Obtain Regex matching Groups using Pattern.asPredicate()

Tags: java, regex, string, java-stream, regex-group

Suppose that I have a list:

```
List<String> dest = Arrays.asList(
    "abc abd 2000",
    "idf owe 1200",
    "jks ldg 789",
    "ccc hhh 2000",
    "www uuu 1000"
);
```

And I'm trying to get the number at the end of every string. The given list has only integers in it, but I'm writing the regex for doubles too:`(\\d+\\.?\\d+)`. In Java 1.8, I wrote the following code:

```
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>(
    dest.stream()
        .filter(Pattern.compile("\\D+\\s\\D+\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d+)").asPredicate())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

What I'm trying to do is - get the `(\\d+\\.?\\d+)` group from each found string, how can I do it?

I was thinking about applying a `Matcher` to each element of the list, but I'm not sure about how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the number at the end of every string...

### Solution 1

Maybe you can solve it without using regex, like so:

```
List<String> response = dest.stream()
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
        .map(r -> r[r.length - 1])
        .toList();
```

---

### Solution 2

If you insist on using regex, you can use:

```
final String regex = "\\D+\\s\\D+\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d+)";
final Pattern compile = Pattern.compile(regex);
List<String> response = dest.stream()
        .map(compile::matcher)
        .filter(Matcher::find)
        .map(r -> r.group(1))
        .toList();
```

---

**Outputs**

```
[2000.55, 1200, 789, 2000, 1000]
```

Comment: Where did `2000.55` come from?

Comment: @英語は苦手 It was a test on my side, just to make sure that my solution work.

Comment: @YoucefLaidani Thanks for providing both solutions, I ended up using your other solution because I actually have to do it without any regex. I wanted to ask you another question btw, suppose that I have a number of type `double` and I want to muliply each element of the stream by it, how can I do it?

Comment: @Javadkhan You can use another maps like so `.map(r -> r.group(1)).map(Double::valueOf).map(v -> v * 100).toList();` note, the response should be `List<Double>` and not `List<String>`

Comment: It would be more efficient to use `.map(r -> Double.parseDouble(r.group(1)) * 100)` to avoid unnecessary boxing.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` keeps or removes elements from the list. If you want to transform stream elements (which you do when you extract the number), use `map`.

Then you can use the regex (along with a `Matcher`) to extract data:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D+\\s\\D+\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d+)");
List<String> mylist = dest.stream()
        .map(s -> {
          Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
          matcher.find();
          return matcher.group(1); //error handling sold seperately
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(mylist);
```

prints

```
[2000, 1200, 789, 2000, 1000]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `.map()` instead of `.filter()`.

```
ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>(
    dest.stream()
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\D+\\s\\D+\\s(\\d+\\.?\\d+)", "$1"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(mylist);
```

output:

```
[2000, 1200, 789, 2000, 1000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are several issues that worth to emphasize:

- In you've code started with a `filter()` operation and that was the right step, because `map()` can't discard an element from the stream, it performs a *one-to-one* transformation. If you need to make sure that an element is valid, you need to apply `filter()` first. Another option would be to use [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation which is meant to perform *one-to-many* transformations, i.e. it turns a stream element into **0+** (*zero or more*) elements and can act like both `filter()` and `map()`. And more importantly, usage of `flatMap()` can improve the performance because would allow to **avoid** processing a valid string with the regex-engine twice (while filtering and while mapping).
- Another important thing to consider is that there's more than one valid representation of `double`: *exponential, hexadecimal, etc*. All options are listed in the documentation of [`Double.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)). Even if we are talking only about a plain decimal floating-point number `1.` and `.9` which don't the regular expression you're using are also valid `double`s. **Note** that Javadoc of `valueOf()` contains a *ready-to-go* regex for validating doubles, which cavers of all the possible (it's really massive and sprinkled with comments, so I'm not posting it here).
- In the regex, you're not testing whether the number is located at the end of the string. In the description, you've said: *"I'm trying to get the number at the end of every string"*. If it's important, you need to prepend `$` denoting that captured string should be located at the very end.
- Lastly, it's redundant to wrap a `List` returned by `Collectors.toList()` with an `ArrayList`.

For simplicity, instead of mentioned regex for checking all the forms of double I would use the following regular expression `"(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+)$"`.

The first part `\\d+\\.?\\d*` would match to a whole number, e.g. `999`, a floating-point number with no fraction part, e.g. `1.`, and a regular floating-point, e.g. `99.999`.

The second part `\\.\\d+` matches a floating-point number without the integer part, e.g. `.995`.

Here how it can be done using Stream API features and [`java.util.regex.MatchResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html).

***Note:*** `Matcher.results()` *was introduced with Java 9, although you mentioned Java 8 I guess this solution can be useful for other readers.*

```
List<String> strings = List.of(
    "abc abd 2000", "idf owe 1200", "jks ldg 789",
    "ccc hhh 2000", "www uuu 1000", "ccc hhh 2000.",
    "abc abd 2000.1", "idf owe 1200.0", "jks ldg 789.995", ".999",     // floated-point numbers
    "abc abd 2000y", "idf owe", "jks ldg 789.995%wtqop", "....ljsofo." // invalid strings
);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+)$");
        
List<String> numbers = strings.stream()
    .flatMap(str ->
        p.matcher(str).results().map(MatchResult::group)
    )
    .toList();
    
System.out.println(numbers);
```

*Output:*

```
[2000, 1200, 789, 2000, 1000, 2000., 2000.1, 1200.0, 789.995, .999]
```

The alternative way of doing this would be to use Java 16 [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) which at eh high level acts almost like `flatMap()` transforming one stream element into zero or more elements, but contrary to `flatMap()` its internal mechanism doesn't require generating a new Stream.

In this case, each string in the stream needs to be transformed into either **0** or **1** string. If the number of elements is large, the overhead of creating empty streams and singleton streams might be significant. Hence, using `mapMulti()` in this scenario would be more beneficial.

That's how it might be implemented (credits to *@Holger* for this idea):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.?\\d*|\\.\\d+)$");
        
List<String> numbers = strings.stream()
    .map(p::matcher)
    .<String>mapMulti((matcher, consumer) -> {
        if (matcher.find()) consumer.accept(matcher.group());
    })
    .toList();
```

Comment: @Holger You're right, I've missed the whole point of `mapMulti()` here. Since `Matcher.results()` already produced a stream, it brings no advantage. Fixed the answer.